# Version 2.0 script causes exception when run under version 3.0

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

WRT [this question](https://superuser.com/q/710764/230163)  -- I got something working by getting the current 'prompt' function as a string and writing a new .ps1 file defining 'prompt'.

In writing the new function, I put the functionality I want to add in a `try/catch` block, and write the existing prompt functionality into a `finally` block.

Not at all ideal, but it works in v2.0. When I run it in v3.0, I get an exception:

`"Control cannot leave a finally block"`

Is there any way to for a script to ask the host for a certain version's behavior?
Thanks for any insights.

Current 'prompt' function consists of:
    `return " > "`
I want to add some functionality to the prompt function, so I write a new temp.ps1 file.  I add my functionality in `try/catch` block, and include the existing in a `finally` block.
The temp.ps1 looks something like:

```
function global:prompt {  
  try {  
    pushd
  }
  catch {
    $errors[0] | fl * -force
  }
  finally {
    return " > "
  }
}
```

This works as expected in v2, causes the "Control cannot leave..."  error in V3.

Comment: Please show your code. No one can point out what's wrong with your code if it can't be seen.

Comment: you can start powershell.exe with the `-v 2` parameter

Comment: @Kayasax -- I don't want to run my version 3 powershell console as version 2, I just want this one script that runs under v2 to run under v3...

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to keep using Powershell V3, you cannot have a return statement in your finally block. See Page 6 of Windows Management Framework 3.0 Release notes: (You shouldn't need a return value there anyways)

http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/B/52B59966-3009-4F39-A99E-3732717BBE2A/WMF3%200%20Beta%20Release%20Notes.docx

Comment: Truly unhelpful, since the exception tells me what the problem is, and yet I still want to run this script in v3.  As for "shouldn't need a return value there anyways", I'm pretty sure the prompt function does have to return a value.  What I'm putting in the finally block is what I get from `cat function:\prompt`, and parsing out the return statement to place outside of the finally block would be complicated.

Comment: I guess the solution is to make sure what ever code I add to the prompt function can't throw an exception, whatever version it is run under, so the try/catch/finally isn't necessary.

Comment: @Number8 Why unhelpfull? Cole9850 gave you the answer ! just echo the output in the finally block is suffisent : `finally {"$pwd > " }`

Comment: Yes Kayasax is right, and I meant it was unnecessary because return statements in finally blocks are bad practice, and not the point of a finally block. You can't do it in Java or C#, why should you be able to do it in PowerShell? Look at the release notes for Microsofts provided "work around"